# Integral of $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}$ using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to follow along to the solution to this post ([$\int_{0}^\pi \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin x} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986377/int-0-pi-frac-sinnx-sin-x-dx))
on how solve this integral using complex analysis methods. I was able to follow along until
we got to the integral
$$\frac{1}{2i}\int_{|z|=1}\left(\frac{1}{z^{n}}\cdot\frac{z^{2n}-1}{z^{2}-1}\right)dz$$ I assume the next step is to apply residue theorem by taking the Laurent series but I have no idea what is a good way to go about that. The answerer simply gave the series they used but I have no idea how they got that series either. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $\frac{z^{2n}-1}{z^2-1}$ is a polynomial...

Comment: Oh good point haha, thanks!

Comment: @user10354138 Hi sorry I can see now why the poles at 1 and -1 cancel out but I do not see why the $z^{-1}$ term is 0 or $\pi$ since I do not know what the simplified polynomial actually is. I also do not know why the answerer in the post I linked took had the integral evaluate to the n-1th derivative of some polynomial.

Comment: $(w^n-1)/(w-1)$ is the geometric sum $1+w+w^2+\cdots+w^{n-1}$.

Comment: @Jochen Right but what about the $(w^{n}+1)/(w+1)$ terms?

Comment: For $w=z^2$ you should see *what the simplified polynomial actually is*.

Comment: Where is your $\frac1{2i}$ from?

Comment: Ah okay I see it now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using
$$ \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k $$
one has
$$ I=\frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=1}\left(\frac{1}{z^{n}}\cdot\frac{1-z^{2n}}{1-z^{2}}\right)dz=\frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z^{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^{2k}dz=\frac{1}{2i}\int_{|z|=1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^{2k-n}dz. $$
So if $n$ is even, then $I=0$ since
$$ \int_{|z|=1}z^{2m}dz=0 $$
If $n$ is odd, then the only term which is not zero is when $2k-n=-1$ or $k=\frac{n-1}{2}$ and hence
$$I=2\pi.$$