# Finding value of $I=\int^{\pi\over2}_0 \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin{x}} \ \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Finding value of $$I=\int^{\pi\over2}_0 \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin{x}} \ \mathrm{d}x.$$

---

I got this question in my book. I got if $n$ is even then $I$ is $0$, by using king's rule it turns out to be $I=-I$.

But I couldn't solve it when $n$ is an odd number. I tried by taking $n=1,3$ and $5$ and simply expanding $\sin (3x)$ and $\sin (5x)$ in terms of $\sin x$ and integrating  I get $I=\pi$. But can it be proved by in general taking $n$, not assuming any particular odd value of $n$.

Comment: Isn't $I = \pi/2$ for $n = 3$ and $n = 5$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986377/int-0-pi-frac-sinnx-sin-x-dx

Comment: The result you are stating is for the integral over $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first deal with the odd one.
Noticing
$$
\begin{aligned}
&2 \sin x[  \cos (2 x)+\cos (4 x)+\ldots+\cos (2 n x)] \\
= & {[\sin (3 x)-\sin (x)]+[\sin (5 x)-\sin (3 x)] } +\ldots +[\sin (2 n+1) x-\sin (2 n-1)] \\
= & \sin (2 n+1) x-\sin x ,
\end{aligned}
$$
we have $$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin (2 n+1) x}{\sin x}dx= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}2[ \cos (2 x)+\cos (4 x)+\ldots+\cos (2 n x)]+1 d x=\frac{\pi}{2} 
$$
Similarly for the even, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
& 2 \sin x[\cos x+\cos (3 x)+\cdots+\cos (2n -1) x] \\
=&[\sin (2 x)-\sin 0]+[\sin (4 x)-\sin 2 x]+\ldots+ [\sin (2nx)-\sin (2(n-1) x \\
=&\sin (2 n x),
\end{aligned}
$$
hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin (2 n x)}{\sin x}dx & =2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left[\cos x+\cos (3 x)+\ldots+\cos (2 n-1)x\right] \\
& =2\left[\frac{\sin x}{1}+\frac{\sin (3 x)}{3}+\cdots+\frac{\sin (2 n-1)x}{2 n-1}\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \\
& =2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2 k-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $$I(n) = \int_0^{0.5\pi} \frac{\sin{(nx)}}{\sin{(x)}}dx$$
Then $$I'(n) = \int_0^{0.5\pi} \frac{\partial}{\partial n}\left(\frac{\sin{(nx)}}{\sin{(x)}}\right)dx=\int_0^{0.5\pi} \frac{1}{{\sin{(x)}}}\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\left({\sin{(nx)}}\right)dx=n\int_0^{0.5\pi} \frac{{\cos{(nx)}}dx}{{\sin{(x)}}}$$
$$
I''(n)=-n^2\int_0^{0.5\pi} \frac{{\sin{(nx)}}dx}{{\sin{(x)}}}
\Rightarrow I(n) = -n^2I''(n)
$$
Solving the ODE:
$$
\frac{d^2I}{{dn}^2}=-I\times n^{-2}
\Rightarrow I^{-1}\frac{d^2I}{{dn}^2}=-n^{-2} \Rightarrow \int \int \frac{dI }{I}dI = -\int \int \frac{dn}{n^2}dn
$$
So we get:
$$ \int C_1 dI + \int \ln{(I)}dI = \int \frac{dn}{n}+\int C_2 dn$$
$$ C_1I + I ln(I) - I = \ln(n)+C_2n + C_3$$
Rearranging for I:
$$
{(e^{c_1-1}I)^I}=ne^{c_2n+C_3}
$$
But we know that $e^{c_1-1}=c_4$
Let $J = c_4I.
$
Then we get:
$${J^J}=(ne^{c_2n+C_3})^{c_4}$$
So
$$ J = e^{W((ne^{c_2n+C_3})^{c_4})}$$
$$ I(n)  = \frac{1}{c_4} e^{W((ne^{c_2n+C_3})^{c_4})}$$
We could find the value of these coefficients by evaluating the original function at different points.
**This if for all $n$ both even and odd**

Answer (score 3):

Start by using the complex definition for $\sin(nx)$,
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}dx$$
You can then expand using geometric series,
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)\left(e^{\left(n-1\right)ix}+e^{\left(n-2\right)ix}e^{-ix}+...+e^{ix}e^{-\left(n-2\right)ix}+e^{-\left(n-1\right)ix}\right)}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}dx$$
Tidy up using summation,
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\left(n-1-k\right)ix}e^{-kix}\right)}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\left(n-1-2k\right)ix}dx$$
Case 1: n is odd.
Split the sum,
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}e^{\left(n-1-2k\right)ix}+\sum_{k=\frac{n+1}{2}}^{n-1}e^{\left(n-1-2k\right)ix}\right)dx$$
Re-index,
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}e^{2kix}+\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}e^{-2kix}\right)dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}2\cos\left(2kx\right)+1\right)dx$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\frac{2\sin\left(k\pi\right)}{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\frac{2\sin\left(0\right)}{2k}+\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2} \text{ for all n>0 odd}.$$
Case 2: n is even.
Split the sum like this,
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}e^{\left(n-1-2k\right)ix}+\sum_{k=\frac{n}{2}}^{n-1}e^{\left(n-1-2k\right)ix}dx$$
Re-index,
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}e^{\left(1+2k\right)ix}+\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}e^{-\left(1+2k\right)ix}dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}2\cos\left(\left(1+2k\right)x\right)dx$$
$$2\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\left(1+2k\right)\pi}{2}\right)}{1+2k}$$
$$2\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{2k-1}$$
Not sure is there is a better solution for the even case.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from @Lai and @Archie Brew final answer, if $n=2m$
$$2\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{2k-1}=\frac{\pi }{2}-(-1)^m \Phi \left(-1,1,m+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ where appears the  Lerch transcendent function.

Computing the very first ones, this generates the sequence
$$\left\{2,\frac{4}{3},\frac{26}{15},\frac{152}{105},\frac{526}{315}
   ,\frac{5156}{3465},\frac{73958}{45045},\frac{67952}{45045},\cdots\right\}$$
The denominators form sequence $A025547$ and the numerators are *twice* the terms of sequence $A007509$ in $OEIS$.

Notice that
$$\Phi \left(-1,1,m+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{2m+3}{4}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{2m+1}{4}\right)\right)$$

Expanding for large values of $m$

$$2\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{2k-1}=\frac{\pi }{2}-(-1)^m\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{E_{2 n} } {4^{n} \, m^{2 n+1}}$$

Comment: Hi! Claude, glad to hear from you.  Your approximation is interesting.

Comment: @Lai. No more an approximation ! Cheers & thanks